# Optimizing layout and multiscreen support

Tags: android, optimization, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, multiscreen

I'am starting a new project that will require a lot of `images`, so I want to optimize everything I can.

The `mainactivity` of the project will have a control panel (with a `menu`), and until now I made this structure:

[image]

So, I will have a linearlayout for zone 1 and 2. 
The zone 1 will have another linearlayout with horizontal orientation.
The zone 2 will have a tablelayout

Is this the best solution for **multiscreen support** and good performance? Or should I make all with `relativelayout`?

Comment: If u can use actionbar as zone 1, then a simple Gridview or a tablelayout without any parentlayout can do the trick

Comment: and I can make the actionbar look like this??

http://s7.postimg.org/9zr8ysidn/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When designing your application to support a wide range of screen sizes, you should use **Fragments** in different layout configurations to optimize the user experience based on the available screen space.

You can add a fragment to the activity during the activity runtime. This is necessary if you plan to change fragments during the life of the activity.

An important rule when dealing with fragments—especially those that you add at runtime—is that the fragment must have a container View in the layout in which the fragment's layout will reside.

In order to replace one fragment with another, you can use an empty FrameLayout that acts as the fragment container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was very helpful. Btw, the objective is to have a dashboard, and when I press a button a new activity should start and hold the full screen. Should I do this with the fragments? (if yes, the dashboard it self has to be a **fragment** right?)